# What is "express" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, contemporary-latin, technology, modern-life

Express buses, express trains, and express lifts — and maybe some other express things — are vehicles that have unusually few stops and are therefore faster than others.
What would be a good way to express (no pun intended) this in Latin?
For example, how to say "express train" in Latin?
The obvious direct translation *tramen expressum* is one option, but the participle *expressus* seems too far from the desired meaning to work.
Of course, one could say "fast train" (for example *tramen celere*) but I wonder if there is something more suitable.
I would prefer a single adjective to a long explanation.

Comment: There is an adverb: *expeditiose.*

Comment: I wonder where you got the word 'tramen'? I can't find a classical origin for it. There has been something of a vogue for 'hamaxostichus', which I personally think clumsy and abhorrent, preferring to adopt the modern Italian 'trena'. You might consider 'trena finite destinata'.

Comment: @Hugh, I couldn't find that adverb in my dictionaries. Did you mean *expedite*? Searching for your adverb lead me to the adjective *expeditus* which is the best fit I have found so far. *Tramen expeditum* sounds like a reasonable option.

Comment: @TomCotton, *tramen* (*traminis*, neuter) is the only Latin word for a train I know. It's in my Finnish–Latin–Finnish dictionary and I'm sure it has occurred in my Latin correspondence and the news Nuntii Latini. Vicipaedia uses it, too. I think it is a combination of *tra-* (=*trans-*) or *trahere* and the instrumental derivative *-men* (=*-mentum*). I am not sure, though. I agree on *hamaxostichus*. Analogy to the Italian 'treno' is a good option, and so is your "train with a goal" translation.

Comment: You're right, the Italian is 'treno'. I've used 'trena' in my own translations to make for convenient inflection, and suggested it here unthinkingly. 'Finite' is a soundly classical adverbial usage, meaning 'with restriction(s)' (Cic. de Fin. 2.9.27), and my 'destinata' (p.p. from destino) was adjectival, to produce 'train intended/ designed/planned with restrictions' — or in other words, an express train.

Comment: Traupman proposes ***tramen, inis, n rapidissimum*** in his *Conversational Latin*, but this isn’t very imaginative :)

Comment: I wonder/can't recall what was the Hogwarts Express called in [Harrius Potter et Philosopi Lapis](https://www.amazon.com/Harrius-Potter-Philosophi-Lapis-Philosophers/dp/1582348251). FWIW, jet is [aërināvis celérrima](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/institutions_connected/latinitas/documents/rc_latinitas_20040601_lexicon_it.html) in the Lexicon Recentis Latinitatis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[David Morgan's lexicon](http://www.wyomingcatholiccollege.com/faculty-pages/patrick-owens/lexicon/adumbratio/index.aspx) (warning: big file) suggests [*citatus, -a, -um*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcito2) for "express" in this context. His suggestions for "express train" are:

> tramen* citatum, hamaxostichus* citatus

(The * indicates that it is a modern word found after AD 1400. I won't comment on which is better, since that's not really the OP's question.)

Here are some sample uses:

> *citato equo* = "at full gallop"
>
> *citatum agmen* = "rapidly marching column"
>
> *citate* (adv.) = "speedily"

Answer (score 2):

You could use the adjective *constans* to mean consistent and continuing. Alternatively, one could use *liquidus*. It primarily means liquid, but it can also be interpreted as flowing or without interruption. There's even *fluentus*, which is the Medieval Latin word for flowing, but mostly describes water. Personally, I would say *vehiculum constans* or *continuing vehicle*. I hope this was useful.

Edit: I also suggest *protinus*, without pause.

Comment: Is _fluentus_ right? I would expect _fluens, -tis_ instead...